# How do I use a custom ReactJs component inside my JSX file from ReactJs.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, reactjs.net

I would like to use the following react component [ImageLoader](https://tonicdev.com/npm/react-imageloader) but i dont understand how to integrate it into my current Asp.net mvc project. I m currently running my own reactJs components from a separate JSX using the help of ReactJs.net.

Comment: Are you asking for a React project or a React Native project?

Comment: i am asking for a walk through on how to use someone else's reusable react component from my jsx file.

Comment: Ok I'm asking because that module is specific for react web and won't work with react native

Comment: react native is for mobile correct? I m not using react native. I am using react in my Asp.net Mvc project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, but it's not a trivial task, because that component is developed using [ES6](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/), or, you could say, a new definition for Javascript (or more exactly, "ECMAscript"). You have two main options:

1) Develop the component yourself. You can access the source code of the component in its [Github Page](https://github.com/hzdg/react-imageloader/blob/master/src/index.js). Even if you are not familiar with ES6, I think the logic behind this component should be easy to figure (I recommend this if you don't want to dig on precompiling and using Npm/Bower/etc).

2) As ES6 is not supported by all browsers at this time (Dec 23, 2015). To make it work properly with your project in Visual Studio, you will need to configure your project to use [NPM and GULP](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/283/asp-net-5-managing-client-side-dependencies-with-npm-bower-and-gulp) and BABEL (look up at the first link for more info) to "pre-compile" the file and be able to use it in your JSX. Using **Bower** or **Npm** you should be able to import that component into your project.

You could also copy and paste the code inside a file in your project a look up to precompile it with Babel for MSBuild.

Either way, you are going to need to be more aware about ES6 and/or precopiling javascript files in Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you have a simple visual studio project with this set? Luckily I still have been able to code the needed components myself, but I would rather get to the point of reusing other components. This would make for a perfect pluralsight video!

Comment: here is a great example of integrating reactjs with Asp.net MVC https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/0216magcode

Comment: Also check out the associated article in MSDN magazine by Graham Mendick